# Howto set the payload length for the lower layer in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

How do I set the lower layer's payload_length field with the size of the upper layer ?

```
import binascii
from scapy.all import *

payload_types = {0: "Upper0", 1: "Upper1"};

class Lower(Packet):
      fields_desc = [ 
            XShortEnumField("payload_type", 0, payload_types),
            IntField("payload_length", 0) ];

class Upper0(Packet):
      fields_desc = [ 
            IntField("data", 0)
      ]

bind_layers(Lower, Upper0, payload_type=0)

class Upper1(Packet):
      fields_desc = [ 
            IntField("data0", 0),
            IntField("data1", 0)
      ]

bind_layers(Lower, Upper1, payload_type=1)

p0=Lower()/Upper0(data=1)
p1=Lower()/Upper1(data0=1,data1=2)
print(binascii.b2a_hex(bytes(p0)))   # 00000000000000000001
print(binascii.b2a_hex(bytes(p1)))   # 0001000000000000000100000002
```

Here `bind_layers` overloads `payload_type` of the lower layer, however how can I connect the dots to also set the `payload_length` ? p0.payload_length should be 4 while p1.payload_length should be 8.
Are there layer examples that implement this that I could look at?